# Electron emitter for the slit experiment

Tags: photons, electrons

I read this in page 12 of Brian Hall's Quantum Theory for Mathematicians:

> In results published in 1989, a team led by Akira Tonomura at Hitachi performed a double-slit experiment in which they were able to record the results one electron at a time. (Similar but less definitive experiments were carried out by Pier Giorgio Merli, GianFranco Missiroli and Giulio Pozzi in Bologna in 1974 and published in the American Journal of Physics in 1976.) In the Hitachi experiment, each electron passes through the slits and then strikes a screen, causing a small spot of light to appear. The location of this spot is then recorded for each electron, one at a time. The key point is that each individual electron strikes the screen at a single point. That is to say, individual electrons are not smeared out across the screen in a wavelike pattern, but rather behave like point particles, in that the observed location of the electron is indeed a point. Each electron, however, strikes the screen at a different point, and once a large number of the electrons have struck and their locations have been recorded, an interference pattern emerges.

I was hoping someone could explain to me the answers to some questions I have about the emitter in electron (and photon) slit experiments like this. I want to understand how this electron emitter was arranged. I mean the region of physical space from which an electron emission is known to come from.

Say the region from which an electron could have come is physically bounded by a box. How small of a box could the emitter be put in and what process was used to emit electrons?

Here's another excerpt from the book:

> Since Taylor’s results suggest that interference remains even when the photons are widely separated, the photons are not interfering with one an- other. Rather, as Paul Dirac put it in Chap. 1 of [6], “Each photon then interferes only with itself.” To state this in a different way, since there is no interference when there is only one slit, Taylor’s results suggest that each individual photon passes through both slits. By the early 1960s, it became possible to perform double-slit experiments with electrons instead of photons, yielding even more dramatic confirmations of the strange behavior of matter in the quantum realm. (See Sect. 1.2.4.)

It's clear the shadow has wave-like properties, but not very clear how the emitter was arranged and what the process is that generates these photons or electrons is. How localized is the emitter in space?

I have heard from other sources that, if you want to observe particle-like behavior instead of interference, you can use detectors to measure which slit the electrons pass through. When you do this, you'll "collapse" the electron's wavefunction into a particle-like state, and you won't observe interference.

What sort of detectors can do this? Is this modified experiment equivalent to simply obstructing the slits in the original experiment?

Comment: Hopefully, in the near future, someone will demonstrate that the essence of this phenomenon revolves around the behavior of photons. When an electron is accelerated through a slit it emits thousands of photons, giving rise to an intricate fringe pattern upon striking the screen. As the electron continues toward the screen, thousands of these emitted photons, upon reflection from the pattern, engage in a continuous interaction with the electron. This dynamic interaction ultimately channels the electron towards specific points that precisely correspond to the observed pattern. IMO

Comment: And yet to see an electron beam one needs something that fluoresces. For the OP one does not need a very large box at all, and small emitter sizes are required for, e.g., good electron microscopes. A standard TEM has order one electron at a time in the column, and makes lovely diffraction patterns from crystals.